# Allowing a user to use sudo without a password

Tags: sudo

On a sandbox VM environment, I have a setup of Ubuntu Linux which is firewalled and cannot be accessed from outside the local system.  Therefore, on that VM, I'd like to give the administrative user (which I set up) the ability to run anything with sudo and not need a password.

While I know this is not secure, this VM is not on all the time, and requires my personal passcode to run.  So even though this is not "secure", is there a way to get the desired functionality?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [man sudoers](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sudoers&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en):

```
   NOPASSWD and PASSWD

   By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself
   before running a command.  This behavior can be modified via the
   NOPASSWD tag.  Like a Runas_Spec, the NOPASSWD tag sets a default for
   the commands that follow it in the Cmnd_Spec_List.  Conversely, the
   PASSWD tag can be used to reverse things.  For example:

    ray  rushmore = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm

   would allow the user ray to run /bin/kill, /bin/ls, and /usr/bin/lprm
   as root on the machine rushmore without authenticating himself.
```

One other tag is `ALL`, to allow the user ray to run any command on any host without password you can use:

```
ray ALL= NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: The configuration file this answer is describing is `/etc/sudoers`. You do not edit this like a normal configuration file, instead you should use the `visudo` command (as root).

Comment: you answer works but if I want to limit it to `/bin/su - david` by adding `ray ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/su - david`, it still asks for password when I run, `/bin/su - david`.  Any idea?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned it is a bad idea to disable the password prompt unless the system runs in a particular secure environment.

One possible solution is this one-liner that I find easier to remember than the NOPASSWD option. Get administrative privileges and run

```
$ visudo
```

and add the following line

> Defaults:  *username*   !authenticate

This will disable the password prompt entirely for a particular user.