# How can I run reboot as a normal user without needing to enter a password?

Tags: debian, sudo

My goal is to use reboot as myusername without entering a password. How can I achieve this?

I have read [Allowing a user to use sudo without a password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/allowing-a-user-to-use-sudo-without-a-password) and followed the suggestions but it still doesn't work for me. Here is my `/etc/sudoers` but it still asks for a password:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myusername  ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/reboot

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I then run

```
sudo reboot
```

and am asked for a password. How can I run `reboot` as a normal user without being asked for a password?

Here is `sudo -l` output :

```
Matching Defaults entries for myusername on this host:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User myusername may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

I also tried with

```
myusername  ALL=NOPASSWD:/bin/ls
```

but `sudo ls` still asked for a password so this seems to be a general problem, not specific to `reboot`.

Comment: You should read at least the first few lines of the `sudo` man page in order to understand the lowest basics of the tool. And after having done that you search in the `sudoers` man page for `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: I amde a couple of changes to your question, you had some of the lines left over from our chat conversation and the one you had left had extra spaces. Please check and make sure that the edited version is _exactly_ the same as what you have. Also, please update your question with the output of `sudo -l`.

Comment: `sudo -l` says you are allowed to run `/sbin/reboot` but you call `sudo reboot`. Get the difference?

Comment: `sudo /sbin/reboot` still asks for [sudo] password and `/sbin/reboot` says reboot:must be superuser

Comment: @HaukeLaging no I don't. The OP has clearly either added `/sbin` to their path or set up an alias as suggested in my answer. What do you think is happening when he runs `reboot` as opposed to `/sbin/reboot`? In any case, `/sbin` is in the `sudo` path as you can see so, again...

Answer (score 10):

First of all, do not, I repeat NOT, attempt to make your user have root privileges at all times, that is the mother of all security risks and is not only unnecessary but asking for trouble.

Anyway, if you want your user to be able to run a specific command, you need to add this line to `sudoers` (change `terdon` to your username of course):

```
terdon ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/reboot
```

You can then run it with `sudo reboot` *without entering a password*. You will always need to run it with `sudo` though, the best you can get is passwordless `sudo` for certain commands.

This is because of the way the system works. When you attempt to run, for example `shutdown -r`, as a normal user, you get this message:

```
$ shutdown -r
shutdown: you must be root to do that!
```

This has nothing to do with `sudo`, the command in question simply checks whether your userid is 1 (the super user) and if it is not, it won't let you run it. You *could* set up your system to have another user as userid 1 but that would simply change the username of `root` and would be a lot of trouble for no reason (and would not help you do what you are attempting anyway).

So, unless you are actually logged in as the user whose userid is 1, you will *always* have to use `sudo` to run privileged commands. The only workaround would be to create an alias (or a function, or a script) for `reboot` in your shells's configuration file (`~/.bashrc` for example):

```
alias reboot='sudo shutdown -r now'
```

That way, since you have already set `shutdown` to be passwordless in `/etc/sudoers`, you will be able to run

```
$ reboot
```

and get your desired result.

Comment: appreciate your answer but I added the `terdon ALL=NOPASSWD:/sbin/reboot` line to /etc/sudoers and rebooted the system. But if I `sudo reboot`, it still asks for password.

Comment: @Level1Coder you did you use actual username and not mine right?

Comment: correct, I replaced terdon with my own username

Comment: @Level1Coder yes, it doesn't seem to work for `reboot`, sorry. I edited and changed to `shutdown -r` instead (which does the same thing). It works fine like that on my Debian.

Comment: @Level1Coder scratch that, it works fine with reboot, I just checked. I'm guessing that you had saved the file but not exited `visudo` when you ran the command. Anyway, using `shutdown -r` is better since it is likelier to work on older machines.

Comment: I'm about to give up, I wanted this downvoted question to have a real answer. I added this to sudoers: `terdon ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /sbin/shutdown` but `sudo shutdown -r now` still asks for password.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13281/discussion-between-terdon-and-level1coder)